# windows 7 returns from sleep with dimmed display

Tags: windows

I installed windows 7 Home Premium on my laptop, the problem I have is that the display is dimmed after the computer returns from sleep.
On power setting I put it on High Performance and set "Dim the display" to "Never" but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

well, a quick litmus test is to

install flux 
( a screen dimmer tool according to the time of the day ), 
and try the same scenario again.

i suggest this because this tool will remember the brightness settings on its own.

based on the results, we can further explore device-driver update, bios-update approach

Comment: I installed Flux, after returning from sleep mode the problem persists.
If I unplug the laptop when the screen is dimmed, and plug it in again, the screen returns to normal brightness.
Everything worked fine before yesterday when I installed Windows 7.

Comment: by anychance this laptop is hp/dell with dual graphics ?

Comment: No, it's a Samsung R540

Comment: can you provide the detailed output of devmgmt.msc ?

Comment: I uploaded an output here: http://www.yourfilelink.com/get.php?fid=2030597  , file name: hwdres.nfo